# Sending byte array ( image stream ) to WCF server using REST

Tags: wcf

I need to develop some REST service that will be able to get image stream ( as byte array ) and return some xml according to this image.

1. How can I develop a REST service that accepts a byte array?
2. How can I add some basic security in REST ? ( i want to add some basic authentication option that will give access to this service only to permission group of users )

Thanks for any help .

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  I'm going to rephrase your questions so "yes,yes" isn't the answer.

Comment: is the `WCF` service in an `intranet`?

Answer (score 0):

Your first Point:

You should use a `Stream` as parameter.

for example

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate ="/uploadFile")]
string UploadFile(Stream fileContents);
```

The stream content could be defined by yourself. Return value is any kind of string, could also been xml.

Your second Point:

You have to add a bit of stuff to your `app.config` or `web.config` => `webHttpBinding` =>

```
    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" />
```

to your service behavior you have to specify how to valid your users credentials

have a look at this from  [`MSDN link`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649647.aspx).

Comment: This returns an `int`?

Comment: The OP want's XML back.